# Notion - Export HTML

Tags: notion-api

Is it possible to receive the HTML from the notion-api. The same function as it is in the GUI?

I know that you can get the Page/Block with an request and receive an JSON which you have do present on your own. Is it possible to request a HTML from the notion-api?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that's currently not possible.

What you could do: Open your Notion page in the browser (`Copy Link`), grab the HTML (`Inspect`) and populate the content through the Notion API.